# pandas and matplotlib plot dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'cities':['A','B','A','B','A','B',],
               'date':['2016-9-1','2016-9-1','2016-9-2','2016-9-2','2016-9-3','2016-9-3'],
               'count':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})
```

And I'd like to plot two scatter plots, one for city 'A' and one for city 'B'. In each plot, x-axis is date, and y-axis is count.

I tried a bit, but the code is so ugly that I am shy from posting it up. Would appreciate somebody to help with some elegant way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't be shy and show us: nothing is uglier than asking for code without sharing its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'cities':['A','B','A','B','A','B',],
               'date':['2016-9-1','2016-9-1','2016-9-2','2016-9-2','2016-9-3','2016-9-3'],
               'count':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})

test.date = pd.to_datetime(test.date)
```

***Solution***

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


gb = test.groupby('cities')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(gb.ngroups)
for i, (name, df) in enumerate(gb):
    ax = axes[i]
    ax.scatter(df['date'].values, df['count'].values)
    ax.set_title(name)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you first need to convert `date` column to `datetime` with `pd.to_datetime` because without that it causes an error with plotting.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov I do!  I forgot that part of the copy/paste... thx

Comment: I'm trying this `testA=test[test.cities=='A']` and then `testA.plot(x=testA['date'],y=testA['count'],kind='scatter')` and I'm getting this error: `KeyError: "['2016-09-01T00:00:00.000000000' '2016-09-02T00:00:00.000000000'\n '2016-09-03T00:00:00.000000000'] not in index"`. Can you explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?